# Clone a group of Gitlab projects or update if project already exists

Tags: bash, git

There's a list of Gitlab projects within one group and SSH links are extracted to a separate file that gets then imported to the `bash` script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t repos < ./repositories.txt

for repo in "${repos[@]}"
do
    git clone "$repo"
done
```

It works perfectly fine when the directory it operates in is empty. Otherwise, I get the following errors:

```
fatal: destination path 'project1' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

It yields error code 128, so I tried adding `OR` condition to the script:

```bash
[...]
git clone "$repo" || find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && git pull origin master" \;
[...]
```

before I realized the iteration is done by a list of URLs, so the script is not aware about directory it should get into, so it simply doesn't work as intended.

So, the question is: how to clone projects into directory if they don't exist there yet, or update them if they do exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#! /bin/sh
set -e

while read repo
do
    repo_name="`basename $repo .git`"
    if test -d "$repo_name"
    then
        git -C "$repo_name" pull
    else
        git clone "$repo"
    fi
done < ./repositories.txt
```

"`basename $repo .git`" extract the repository name from the URL and cuts `.git` from the end (if it's there). See [`man basename`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename).

Comment: It works perfectly in WSL, but when I launch it in alpine docker container (with `bash` installed), the script clones all repositories on the first run, but on the next runs, the instructions move to the `else` clause, although repo directories already exist. What's different between WSL and Alpine environments?

Comment: Utility function to tell if path passed as argument is a git repository `is_git(){ git -C "${1:?}" rev-parse --git-dir >/dev/null 2>&1;}`

Comment: @AbreQueVoy That requires debugging. Run the script with `bash -x` for debugging trace,

Comment: @LéaGris I took `git -C` advice but for a different purpose. :-) The problem of the topicstarter is that the code sometimes ignores the existing directory, not that it tries to update non-git directory.

Comment: OK, so running `bash -x` gives the following output:
`+ set -e
+ read repository
++ basename $'git@example.com:repository/Project1.git\r' .git`
Tried to get rid of the `\r` adding `| tr -d '\r'` but it doesn't work here. Will update you once I find something working.

Comment: @AbreQueVoy DOS line endings? Well `tr -d` works for me: `echo -e '\r' | cat -e` produces `^M$`, `echo -e '\r' | tr -d '\r' | cat -e` returns just `$`. `sed` also works: `echo -e '\r' | sed 's/\r//g' | cat -e` -> `$`

Comment: @phd: Picked up the solution with `sed` as I'm more familiar with it. Simply doing: `sed -i 's/\r//g' ./repositories.txt` before reading lines helped to get rid of `\r`'s. Thanks again!